# Filters in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

```
const { connectionType: PersonConnection } = connectionDefinitions({
    name: 'Person',
    nodeType: PersonType,
```

here i am using connectionFields for count

```
    connectionFields: {
        count: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve: (args) => {
                const filter = args.args || {};
                return Person.count(filter).exec();
            },
        },
    },
});
```

i am quite confused about using `args` with custom filters and obtain data from database, using filter
if i don't provide any `id` `count` should provide all data count, if i provide any `id` it may also look for `references` data and search in another models so how to perform the count and efficient filteration of data.
Thanks in Advance

```
person: {
    type: PersonConnection,
    args: _.assign({
        _id: { type: GraphQLID },
        // assign mine custom filters
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        location: { type: GraphQLString },
        education: { type: GraphQLString },
    }, connectionArgs),
    resolve: (obj, args, auth, fieldASTs) => {
        const filter = args;
        return connectionFromPromisedArray(getPersons(filter, fieldASTs), args).then((data) => {
            // using to connection Fields
            data.args = filter;
            return data;
        }).catch(err => new Error(err));
    },
},
```